# Aircraft ifFlying status change not observed in key manager class

Tags: dji-sdk

I setup a listener on the key DJIFlightControllerParamIsFlying on my Mavic Air.  It never gets called.

let flyingKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamIsFlying)

```
    DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.startListeningForChanges(on: flyingKey!, withListener: self, andUpdate: { (oldValue: DJIKeyedValue?, newValue: DJIKeyedValue?) in
        Logger.sharedLogger.log(message: "Received flying status change", event: "Notice", fileName: #file,line: #line,funcName: #function)                
    })
```

Is there something else I need do to enable that message?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should check for keyManager not to be nil:

```
guard let km = DJISDKManager.keyManager() else {
    // handle error 
    return
}

km.startListeningForChanges(on: flyingKey!, withListener: self, andUpdate: { (oldValue: DJIKeyedValue?, newValue: DJIKeyedValue?) in
    Logger.sharedLogger.log(message: "Received flying status change", event: "Notice", fileName: #file,line: #line,funcName: #function)                
})
```

KeyManager may return nil if this is called before the registration.

Comment: That was it!  Was registering the listener too soon.